# Proportion of a certain number in a vector with 1 hundred position

Tags: python, python-2.7, vector

i need to create a vector with 100 random number between (0,3) and find the proportion of those whom are 2, for each 10 position of the vector, can somebody help me?

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you want. Can you provide an example, and furthermore, what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a list with 100 random numbers, then loop over that list in chunks of 10, count the number of 2's and then multiply by 10 which will give you the percentage

```
from random import randint
l=[]
l = [randint(0,3) for i in xrange(100)]
for i in xrange(0,100,10):
    print l[i:i+10].count(2)*10

10
10
20
20
10
0
30
20
30
20
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have something like this:

randomNums = [randint(0,3) for _ in range(100)]

then you can use the `step` parameter in the `range` function, as well as the `len()` function:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> randomNums = [randint(0,3) for _ in range(100)]
>>> proportions = [len(list(x for x in randomNums[i:i+10] if x == 2))/10 for i in range(0,100,10)]
            #the third number in range(start,end,step) specifies to increment numbers by step ^
                      #^ create a list of all the 2's in a certain slice range
                   ^ divide the len of that list by 10                ^to get proportion
```

this will return a list of length 10 that has the proportions of 2 for every 10 elements:

```
>>> randomNums
[1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ #adding breaks to more clearly see groups of 10
 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, \
 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, \
 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, \ 
 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, \
 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, \
 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, \
 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, \
 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, \
 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]
>>> proportions
[0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]
```